# How to set shipping price for items under 10$ only in Magento?

Tags: magento

How can I set the shipping cost for Magento for all carts that are below a certain price. All carts under £10 to have fixed shipping of £3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

Disable Free shipping in Shipping Method. Then go to Shopping Cart Price Rule and make one.

Conditions: Subtotal equals or greater than 10

Actions: Free Shipping > For matching items only

Save and its working!